# Use Community Search Bar to only search active user profiles

Tags: community, global-search

I would like to have the Global Community search bar only search the profiles of active users.  It seems to search both active & active users.  Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

IF YOU HAVE COMMUNITY PLUS LOGIN LICENSES.

You can uncheck the checkbox `Allow user to see other community` user in `Community Worksapces > Administration`. Also remove `View All Users` system permissions from community  user profiles and disable user visibility checkboxes in sharing setting.

Mark the External sharing of users as private and then create 2 sharing rules.

1. For community users and share only active users with them.
2. For guest user if your community is public.

Comment: I am trying to do what you said but am running into problems.  I disabled the Allow user to see other community users.  That worked as expected as my users can no longer see other community users.  However, the sharing rule is not working.  I created a sharing rule on the User object that says that a public group that contains my community members should have read access if the Active field is true.  I have many other sharing rules that are working so I feel that I know what I am doing.  Thoughts?  I am wondering if the Community profile doesn't have access to the Active field.

Comment: I have customer community portal login licenses.  Does that make a difference with sharing capabilities?

Comment: I think I got it to work.  I needed to create the sharing rule on the community settings page.  Thanks for your help.